Can't Install PIP Gradio
D:\XTTS-RVC-UI>pip install gradio
Collecting gradio
  Using cached gradio-4.40.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
Collecting aiofiles<24.0,>=22.0 (from gradio)
  Using cached aiofiles-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.7 kB)
Collecting anyio<5.0,>=3.0 (from gradio)
  Using cached anyio-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting fastapi (from gradio)
  Using cached fastapi-0.112.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (27 kB)
Collecting ffmpy (from gradio)
  Using cached ffmpy-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
Collecting gradio-client==1.2.0 (from gradio)
  Using cached gradio_client-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.1 kB)
Collecting httpx>=0.24.1 (from gradio)
  Using cached httpx-0.27.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.2 kB)
Collecting huggingface-hub>=0.19.3 (from gradio)
  Using cached huggingface_hub-0.24.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Collecting importlib-resources<7.0,>=1.3 (from gradio)
  Using cached importlib_resources-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2<4.0 in d:\xtts-rvc-ui\venv\lib\site-packages (from gradio) (3.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe~=2.0 in d:\xtts-rvc-ui\venv\lib\site-packages (from gradio) (2.1.5)
Collecting matplotlib~=3.0 (from gradio)
  Using cached matplotlib-3.9.1.tar.gz (36.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [238 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660 C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\.mesonpy-cs626egc -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\.mesonpy-cs626egc\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.5.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660
      Build dir: C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\.mesonpy-cs626egc
      Build type: native build
      Program python3 found: YES
      Project name: matplotlib
      Project version: 3.9.1
      Activating VS 17.10.5
      C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.40.33813 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.40.33813 for x64")
      C linker for the host machine: link link 14.40.33813.0
      C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.40.33813 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.40.33813 for x64")
      C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.40.33813.0
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Program python found: YES (D:\XTTS-RVC-UI\venv\Scripts\python.exe)
      Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.12
      Did not find pkg-config by name 'pkg-config'
      Found pkg-config: NO
      pybind11-config found: YES (C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Scripts\pybind11-config.EXE) 2.13.1
      Run-time dependency pybind11 found: YES 2.13.1
      Downloading freetype-2.6.1 source from https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-old/freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz

      Executing subproject freetype-2.6.1

      freetype-2.6.1| Project name: freetype2
      freetype-2.6.1| Project version: 2.6.1
      freetype-2.6.1| C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.40.33813 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.40.33813 for x64")
      freetype-2.6.1| C linker for the host machine: link link 14.40.33813.0
      freetype-2.6.1| Configuring ftconfig.h using configuration
      freetype-2.6.1| ..\subprojects\freetype-2.6.1\meson.build:174: WARNING: Got an empty configuration_data() object and found no substitutions in the input file 'ftconfig.h'. If you want to copy a file to the build dir, use the 'copy:' keyword argument added in 0.47.0
      freetype-2.6.1| Configuring ftoption.h using configuration
      freetype-2.6.1| Build targets in project: 3
      freetype-2.6.1| Subproject freetype-2.6.1 finished.

      Downloading qhull source from https://github.com/qhull/qhull/archive/v8.0.2/qhull-8.0.2.tar.gz

      Executing subproject qhull

      qhull| Project name: qhull
      qhull| Project version: 8.0.2
      qhull| C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.40.33813 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.40.33813 for x64")
      qhull| C linker for the host machine: link link 14.40.33813.0
      qhull| Build targets in project: 4
      qhull| Subproject qhull finished.

      Run-time dependency dl found: NO (tried builtin and system)
      Library comctl32 found: YES
      Library ole32 found: YES
      Library psapi found: YES
      Library shell32 found: YES
      Library user32 found: YES
      Configuring _version.py using configuration
      Program C:/Users/Muhammad Huzaifa/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-9p7t40hs/matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660/tools/generate_matplotlibrc.py found: YES (D:\XTTS-RVC-UI\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Muhammad Huzaifa/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-9p7t40hs/matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660/tools/generate_matplotlibrc.py)
      Build targets in project: 14

      matplotlib 3.9.1

        Subprojects
          freetype-2.6.1: YES 1 warnings
          qhull         : YES

        User defined options
          Native files  : C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\.mesonpy-cs626egc\meson-python-native-file.ini
          buildtype     : release
          b_ndebug      : if-release
          b_vscrt       : md

      Found ninja.EXE-1.11.1.git.kitware.jobserver-1 at "C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\normal\Scripts\ninja.EXE"
      + meson compile
      [1/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftfntfmt.c.obj
      [2/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftbdf.c.obj
      [3/101] Compiling C++ object extern/agg24-svn/libagg.a.p/src_agg_bezier_arc.cpp.obj
      [4/101] Compiling C++ object extern/agg24-svn/libagg.a.p/src_agg_image_filters.cpp.obj
      [5/101] Compiling C++ object extern/agg24-svn/libagg.a.p/src_agg_trans_affine.cpp.obj
      [6/101] Compiling C++ object extern/agg24-svn/libagg.a.p/src_agg_vpgen_segmentator.cpp.obj
      [7/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftbbox.c.obj
      [8/101] Compiling C++ object extern/agg24-svn/libagg.a.p/src_agg_curves.cpp.obj
      [9/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftbitmap.c.obj
      [10/101] Compiling C++ object extern/agg24-svn/libagg.a.p/src_agg_vcgen_contour.cpp.obj
      [11/101] Compiling C++ object extern/agg24-svn/libagg.a.p/src_agg_vcgen_dash.cpp.obj
      [12/101] Compiling C++ object extern/agg24-svn/libagg.a.p/src_agg_vcgen_stroke.cpp.obj
      [13/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftinit.c.obj
      [14/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftfstype.c.obj
      [15/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftmm.c.obj
      [16/101] Compiling C++ object extern/ttconv/libttconv.a.p/ttutil.cpp.obj
      [17/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftcid.c.obj
      [18/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftotval.c.obj
      [19/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftglyph.c.obj
      [20/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftlcdfil.c.obj
      [21/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftgxval.c.obj
      [22/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftgasp.c.obj
      [23/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftpfr.c.obj
      [24/101] Linking static target extern/agg24-svn/libagg.a
      [25/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftpatent.c.obj
      [26/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftsynth.c.obj
      [27/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_autofit_autofit.c.obj
      [28/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_bzip2_ftbzip2.c.obj
      [29/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_fttype1.c.obj
      [30/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftbase.c.obj
      [31/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftsystem.c.obj
      [32/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftwinfnt.c.obj
      [33/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_base_ftstroke.c.obj
      [34/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_pcf_pcf.c.obj
      [35/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_cid_type1cid.c.obj
      [36/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_lzw_ftlzw.c.obj
      [37/101] Compiling C++ object extern/ttconv/libttconv.a.p/pprdrv_tt2.cpp.obj
      [38/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_cache_ftcache.c.obj
      [39/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/builds_windows_ftdebug.c.obj
      [40/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_pshinter_pshinter.c.obj
      [41/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_raster_raster.c.obj
      [42/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_bdf_bdf.c.obj
      [43/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_smooth_smooth.c.obj
      [44/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_pfr_pfr.c.obj
      [45/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_psnames_psnames.c.obj
      [46/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_psaux_psaux.c.obj
      [47/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_sfnt_sfnt.c.obj
      [48/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_type42_type42.c.obj
      [49/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_type1_type1.c.obj
      [50/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_geom2_r.c.obj
      [51/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_gzip_ftgzip.c.obj
      [52/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_mem_r.c.obj
      [53/101] Compiling C++ object extern/ttconv/libttconv.a.p/pprdrv_tt.cpp.obj
      [54/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_winfonts_winfnt.c.obj
      [55/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_cff_cff.c.obj
      [56/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_usermem_r.c.obj
      [57/101] Linking static target extern/ttconv/libttconv.a
      [58/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_libqhull_r.c.obj
      [59/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_random_r.c.obj
      [60/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_stat_r.c.obj
      [61/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_userprintf_rbox_r.c.obj
      [62/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_qset_r.c.obj
      [63/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_userprintf_r.c.obj
      [64/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_poly_r.c.obj
      [65/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_geom_r.c.obj
      [66/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_user_r.c.obj
      [67/101] Compiling C++ object src/_image.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_image_wrapper.cpp.obj
      FAILED: src/_image.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_image_wrapper.cpp.obj
      "cl" "-Isrc\_image.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p" "-Isrc" "-I..\src" "-I..\extern\agg24-svn\include" "-IC:\Program" "-IC:\Users\Muhammad" "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\Include" "-DNDEBUG" "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/Zc:__cplusplus" "/W2" "/EHsc" "/std:c++17" "/permissive-" "/O2" "/Gw" "Files\Python312\Include" "Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include" "/d2FH4-" "-DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL__image_ARRAY_API" "/Fdsrc\_image.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p\_image_wrapper.cpp.pdb" /Fosrc/_image.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_image_wrapper.cpp.obj "/c" ../src/_image_wrapper.cpp
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files\Python312\Include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Files\Python312\Include' ignored
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include' ignored
      ../src/_image_wrapper.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pybind11/pybind11.h': No such file or directory
      [68/101] Compiling C++ object src/_image.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/py_converters_11.cpp.obj
      FAILED: src/_image.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/py_converters_11.cpp.obj
      "cl" "-Isrc\_image.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p" "-Isrc" "-I..\src" "-I..\extern\agg24-svn\include" "-IC:\Program" "-IC:\Users\Muhammad" "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\Include" "-DNDEBUG" "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/Zc:__cplusplus" "/W2" "/EHsc" "/std:c++17" "/permissive-" "/O2" "/Gw" "Files\Python312\Include" "Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include" "/d2FH4-" "-DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL__image_ARRAY_API" "/Fdsrc\_image.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p\py_converters_11.cpp.pdb" /Fosrc/_image.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/py_converters_11.cpp.obj "/c" ../src/py_converters_11.cpp
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files\Python312\Include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Files\Python312\Include' ignored
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include' ignored
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\py_converters_11.h(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pybind11/pybind11.h': No such file or directory
      [69/101] Compiling C++ object src/_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_path_wrapper.cpp.obj
      FAILED: src/_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_path_wrapper.cpp.obj
      "cl" "-Isrc\_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p" "-Isrc" "-I..\src" "-I..\..\..\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_core\include" "-I..\extern\agg24-svn\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\Include" "-IC:\Program" "-IC:\Users\Muhammad" "-DNDEBUG" "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/Zc:__cplusplus" "/W2" "/EHsc" "/std:c++17" "/permissive-" "/O2" "/Gw" "Files\Python312\Include" "Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include" "-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" "-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1" "/d2FH4-" "-DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL__path_ARRAY_API" "/Fdsrc\_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p\_path_wrapper.cpp.pdb" /Fosrc/_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_path_wrapper.cpp.obj "/c" ../src/_path_wrapper.cpp
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files\Python312\Include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Files\Python312\Include' ignored
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include' ignored
      ../src/_path_wrapper.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pybind11/pybind11.h': No such file or directory
      [70/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_merge_r.c.obj
      [71/101] Compiling C++ object src/_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/py_converters_11.cpp.obj
      FAILED: src/_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/py_converters_11.cpp.obj
      "cl" "-Isrc\_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p" "-Isrc" "-I..\src" "-I..\..\..\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_core\include" "-I..\extern\agg24-svn\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\Include" "-IC:\Program" "-IC:\Users\Muhammad" "-DNDEBUG" "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/Zc:__cplusplus" "/W2" "/EHsc" "/std:c++17" "/permissive-" "/O2" "/Gw" "Files\Python312\Include" "Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include" "-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" "-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1" "/d2FH4-" "-DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL__path_ARRAY_API" "/Fdsrc\_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p\py_converters_11.cpp.pdb" /Fosrc/_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/py_converters_11.cpp.obj "/c" ../src/py_converters_11.cpp
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files\Python312\Include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Files\Python312\Include' ignored
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include' ignored
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\py_converters_11.h(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pybind11/pybind11.h': No such file or directory
      [72/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_io_r.c.obj
      [73/101] Compiling C object subprojects/freetype-2.6.1/libfreetype.a.p/src_truetype_truetype.c.obj
      [74/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_poly2_r.c.obj
      [75/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_global_r.c.obj
      [76/101] Compiling C object subprojects/qhull-8.0.2/libqhull_r.a.p/src_libqhull_r_rboxlib_r.c.obj
      [77/101] Compiling C++ object src/_c_internal_utils.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_c_internal_utils.cpp.obj
      FAILED: src/_c_internal_utils.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_c_internal_utils.cpp.obj
      "cl" "-Isrc\_c_internal_utils.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p" "-Isrc" "-I..\src" "-IC:\Program" "-IC:\Users\Muhammad" "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\Include" "-DNDEBUG" "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/Zc:__cplusplus" "/W2" "/EHsc" "/std:c++17" "/permissive-" "/O2" "/Gw" "Files\Python312\Include" "Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include" "/d2FH4-" "-DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL__c_internal_utils_ARRAY_API" "/Fdsrc\_c_internal_utils.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p\_c_internal_utils.cpp.pdb" /Fosrc/_c_internal_utils.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_c_internal_utils.cpp.obj "/c" ../src/_c_internal_utils.cpp
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files\Python312\Include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Files\Python312\Include' ignored
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include' ignored
      ../src/_c_internal_utils.cpp(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pybind11/pybind11.h': No such file or directory
      [78/101] Compiling C++ object src/_backend_agg.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/py_converters.cpp.obj
      [79/101] Compiling C++ object src/ft2font.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/ft2font_wrapper.cpp.obj
      ../src/ft2font_wrapper.cpp(53): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
      ../src/ft2font_wrapper.cpp(88): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
      ../src/ft2font_wrapper.cpp(106): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
      ../src/ft2font_wrapper.cpp(897): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
      [80/101] Compiling C++ object src/_path.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/py_converters.cpp.obj
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files\Python312\Include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Files\Python312\Include' ignored
      cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include', object file assumed
      cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include' ignored
      [81/101] Compiling C++ object src/ft2font.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/py_converters.cpp.obj
      [82/101] Compiling C++ object src/_backend_agg.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_backend_agg.cpp.obj
      [83/101] Compiling C++ object src/ft2font.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/ft2font.cpp.obj
      [84/101] Compiling C++ object src/_backend_agg.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/_backend_agg_wrapper.cpp.obj
      ../src/_backend_agg_wrapper.cpp(222): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(738): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'double', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(738): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
      ../src/_backend_agg_wrapper.cpp(222): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void RendererAgg::draw_text_image<numpy::array_view<agg::int8u,2>>(GCAgg &,ImageArray &,int,int,double)' being compiled
              with
              [
                  ImageArray=numpy::array_view<agg::int8u,2>
              ]
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(744): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'double', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(745): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'double', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(745): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'double', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(746): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'double', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(842): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'double', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(842): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
      ../src/_backend_agg_wrapper.cpp(285): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void RendererAgg::draw_image<numpy::array_view<agg::int8u,3>>(GCAgg &,double,double,ImageArray &)' being compiled
              with
              [
                  ImageArray=numpy::array_view<agg::int8u,3>
              ]
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(843): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'double', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(843): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'double', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(844): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'double', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(348): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(348): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
      ../src/_backend_agg_wrapper.cpp(197): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void RendererAgg::draw_path<mpl::PathIterator>(GCAgg &,PathIterator &,agg::trans_affine &,agg::rgba &)' being compiled
              with
              [
                  PathIterator=mpl::PathIterator
              ]
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(479): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void RendererAgg::_draw_path<RendererAgg::draw_path::sketch_t>(path_t &,bool,const RendererAgg::facepair_t &,GCAgg &)' being compiled
              with
              [
                  path_t=RendererAgg::draw_path::sketch_t
              ]
      C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p7t40hs\matplotlib_5a626c58ab694696a187fb52db4c4660\src\_backend_agg.h(348): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data
      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
      Activating VS 17.10.5
      INFO: automatically activated MSVC compiler environment
      INFO: autodetecting backend as ninja
      INFO: calculating backend command to run: "C:\Users\Muhammad Huzaifa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9tmao3b6\normal\Scripts\ninja.EXE"
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

i see these everytime.i want to run some local ai tools but cant insall gradio. please help as i need them for my project. i tried all my possible ways like add --pre in the end aswell but  cant figure out why is that coming also i am having latest py version
i see these everytime.i want to run some local ai tools but cant insall gradio. please help as i need them for my project. i tried all my possible ways like add --pre in the end aswell but  cant figure out why is that coming also i am having latest py version.

It looks like you are on a Windows system, so this might be a problem. There are precompiled binaries for Linux systems.

You do not appear to be using an activated virtual environment. As can be seen on PyPi:

It is best to install Gradio in a virtual environment.

The docs describes a virtual environment:

A virtual environment in Python is a self-contained directory that holds a Python installation for a particular version of Python, along with a number of additional packages. This environment is isolated from the main Python installation and other virtual environments. Each environment can have its own independent set of installed Python packages, which allows you to maintain different versions of libraries for different projects without conflicts. Using virtual environments ensures that you can work on multiple Python projects on the same machine without any conflicts. This is particularly useful when different projects require different versions of the same library. It also simplifies dependency management and enhances reproducibility, as you can easily share the requirements of your project with others.

It goes further to give guidelines for installing Gradio on a Windows system in a virtual environment:

Create a Virtual Environment: Open Command Prompt and navigate to your project directory. Then create a virtual environment using the following command:

python -m venv gradio-env

This command creates a new directory gradio-env in your project folder, containing a fresh Python installation.

Activate the Virtual Environment: To activate the virtual environment, run:

.\gradio-env\Scripts\activate

Your command prompt should now indicate that you are working inside gradio-env. Note: you can choose a different name than gradio-env for your virtual environment in this step.

Install Gradio: Now, you can install Gradio using pip:

pip install gradio


Verification: To verify the installation, run python and then type:

import gradio as gr
print(gr.__version__)

This will display the installed version of Gradio.
See the docs.
